# AutoCAD Map 3D does not show panels and icons?

Tags: autocad-map

I have some problems with autocad 2014, 3D map, this not show me de icons on the top, I use windows 10.

[image]

Comment: What icons would you like to see? I see you have the ribbon and the pulldown menu bar.

Comment: Open button, new window from the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are missing you quick access toolbar.

[image]

If you open your Custom User Interface (type CUI at the command line) and set the current workspace to "current" even if it is already current, that should help. [See other ways you could try to get it back here:](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/autocad-forum/quick-access-toolbar-missing/td-p/2591992)

You can also click on the small triangle to the right of the big blue"**A**" in the upper left corner of the image for to the same menus.